# How to add variable insdide of redirect statement?

Tags: php, html

How to redirect to `A.com/status`

Is it posible to double redirect ? for example I want go to `A.com/status` and to one of my controller(Update)

```
public function update_order(){
    $nom = 'status'; 
    $data=  array(
        'status' => 'confirmed' 
        );

    $this->data->simpanupdateorder($nom,$data);
    **redirect('http://A.com/'echo $nom);**
}
```

Comment: use redirect('http://A.com/'.$nom); or redirect("http://A.com/{$nom}");

Comment: You don't write `echo` when you're concatenating strings. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score -1):

```
return redirect()->action('UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

or

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects